# Writing a query to obtain soil data from lat/lon in USA?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, usa, python

I would like to access soil data by lat/lon. It looks like this is the US soil web service [here](https://SDMDataAccess.sc.egov.usda.gov/Spatial/SDMWGS84Geographic.wfs).  However, I am not sure how to set up the query, the [Help](https://sdmdataaccess.nrcs.usda.gov/QueryHelp.aspx#Samples) page should be helpful but is 100's of pages long. Can anyone give me some pointers for setting up a python script to query a [soil database](https://sdmdataaccess.nrcs.usda.gov/)?

R looks like it has a decent [interface](https://ncss-tech.github.io/AQP/), maybe I will have to learn R.

Comment: Since you've already identified your data source and your question is really more about using a software interface to the database, you might want to post this question in [https://stackoverflow.com/](https://stackoverflow.com/).  When you ask a question there, make sure you show what you've tried and what you hope to achieve.

Comment: Your request is a classic case for GIS analysis.  Try SE Geographic Information Systems

Comment: https://sdmdataaccess.sc.egov.usda.gov/WebServiceHelp.aspx may or may not be helpful, but this appears to be a fairly generic WFS/WCS server

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer.

If you visit https://sdmdataaccess.sc.egov.usda.gov/QueryHelp.aspx and download the "Table Column Descriptions Report (741K)" PDF, you will get a list of all tables (and column names) for your data.

You can then go to https://sdmdataaccess.sc.egov.usda.gov/Query.aspx and make queries like `SELECT * FROM chaashto`. You will have to queue your query and give your email address.

I did this and got back a link to a 30M ZIP file (it's https://sdmdataaccess.sc.egov.usda.gov/SDMQueuedDownloads/SDMQuery229984.zip but may no longer be available) that decompresses to 195M. I have no idea what the data means, but, presumably, you would :)